# Replace ‘published on date’ with ‘modified on date’ on Posts

Tags: posts, themes, date, seo

Okay, so I have googled this for the past few hours and even though I am getting closer, I am still stuck.

Problem: If I posted an article on December 15th 2016 but I NOW I updated the same article today(July 20th 2017), when you view the article, the updated/modified date is never shown to the user.

NOTE: I did google it and I am able to display the modified date thanks to articles on WPBeginner etc BUT, how do I only post ONE? If the post is updated, it should post JUST the new modified date/time, not both.

I was leaning towards IF and ELSE statements but I can’t figure out how to set it up like this…

*** If post was modified, post modified date, else post date it was published. ***

If someone can please help me out here, I would appreciate it a lot, I am lost, thanks!

Comment: how about posting the code? kinda hard to help you with your code without seeing it

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for replying. Issue is I am lost and don't really know where to start.

'<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &middot; <?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></p>'

This is the code that I need to be replaced with 'get_the_modified_time' if the post is updated otherwise return to the original code.

Comment: This depends on theme. You can use themes provided hooks to modify the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compare values of `get_the_post_time()` and `get_the_modified_time()`.

```
if ( get_the_post_time() == get_the_modified_time() ) {
    // Published on...
} else {
    // Modified on...
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks this is what I need, I will try this and report back, thanks again for the head start!

Comment: I did it!! Thanks a lot Belinus and everyone who replied!